# How to extract last three chars from word if they are uppercase?

Tags: python, regex

How to extract last three chars from word if they are uppercase?

```
a = "aaaAAA"
b = "bbbbBBB"
c = "ccc CCC"
d = "dddddDDD"
e = "eeeEEEE"
```

My function:

```py
def get_three(value):
    search = re.search("[A-Z]{3}$", value)
    
    if search:
        return search.group(0)
 
     return "NONE"
```

It returns:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
EEE
```

but should be:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
NONE
```

because there is `EEEE` at the end, not `EEE`.

Comment: Use a negative lookbehind that prohibits an uppercase letter before the match.

Comment: The description of what you want to match doesn't describe the problem. The last 3 characters of `eeeEEEE` are uppercase. You never said that the string couldn't have other uppercase characters beside that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]{3}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fKrkuV/1).

*Details*:

- `(?<![A-Z])` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is an uppercase letter immediately to the left of the current location
- `[A-Z]{3}` - three uppercase letters
- `$` - end of string.

If you need to support any Unicode uppercase letters:

```py
import sys

pLu = '[{}]'.format("".join([chr(i) for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if chr(i).isupper()]))
pattern = fr'(?<!{pLu}){pLu}{{3}}$'
```